# How to add a pin at the default location for a google maps web part in Kentico 9?

Tags: google-maps, kentico

I don't see any option to put a pin at the default location for the Google Maps web part. How do I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Why is this being down-voted??? Isn't this what this is for?

Answer (score 0):

Define "Default Location", are you talking about the user's current location? Or some location you determine?

If it's the user's default location, you would have to employ javascript (as this logic pretty much has to be done client side, you can use MaxMind GeoLocate if you wish to do server side, but that's another topic).

Check this example out, you would just add some javascript like this and point it to the map you are generating with Kentico.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geolocation

Comment: By default location I mean the Default Lat/Lon in the web part

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've filled in the "Default Latitude" and "Default Longitude" fields and you've unchecked the "Hide if no record found" checkbox, the pin will show automatically.  If you have not unchecked that box and there are no records, the webpart will be hidden.

** EDIT **
Based on answers from the OP, using the Static Google Maps and having the lat and long fields filled in with valid coordinates, it will auto populate the pin.

Also there were issues with the Google Maps API which were resolved in v9 hotfixes 32 and 36 so if you can apply those hotfixes it should help to resolve the problem.

Comment: Default Lat/Lon are provided and the "hide if no record found" is unchecked, still no pin

Comment: When you view the published page, are there any errors?  Specifically javascript?  Might be you need to add your Google Key or there is some other issue with the lat and long.

Comment: The api key is in place. It doesn't get any errors, just a warning saying "SensorNotRequired" but I don't think that's related

Comment: Which webpart are you using?  Is it the static google map or the one looking for pages in the content tree?  Only the static google map will work properly with the default pin, the others rely on data in the content tree.

Comment: Static "Google Maps" web part

Comment: I've tested this out on my site and had no issues.  Added the "Static Google Maps" webpart to the page template, added the key for my domain, added a correct lat and long and pin shows up without issue.  What hotfix are you on?  There was a fix put out in HF 32 and 36 in v9 to resolve some errors and this may be the issue now.

Comment: Ah - I was using a "Google Maps" web part. Did not realize there was a specific "Static Google Maps" web part. Now the pin is there, but the map width is in pixels... I need it to be 100%, is there any way to do that?
Thanks! 

Edit: never mind, clicked the little arrow to edit the "width" part and it accepted "%"

Answer (score 0):

The "Default latitude" and "Default longitude" settings of the "Google maps" webpart are **not** used for setting a **default pin**, but for **centering** the map at the given point on page load.

You could use JavaScript to add a pin to the map.

1. Set the "Default latitude", "Default longitude" and "Detailed view scale" properties on the "Google maps" webpart
2. Inspect the webpart on the live view of the page, and find the ID of the container. The container ID is the actual ID of the map instance. [image: map container id]
3. Use the `addGoogleMarker` JavaScript function to add the pin to the map, using the ID obtained in step 2.
   The signature of the function is:
   `addGoogleMarker(map, latitude, longitude, title, content, zoom, iconURL)`
   To do this, add a "Javascript" webpart, with the script page location set to "Startup script", and the "In-line script" property set to the following:

   ```js
   addLoadEvent(function() {
        var mapInstance = p_lt_ctl00_GoogleMapsWithUniqueID_map;
        var latitude = {%WebPart.GetValue("GoogleMapsWithUniqueID", "Latitude")%};
        var longitude = {%WebPart.GetValue("GoogleMapsWithUniqueID", "Longitude")%};
        var zoomScale = {%WebPart.GetValue("GoogleMapsWithUniqueID", "ZoomScale")%};

        addGoogleMarker(mapInstance, latitude, longitude, '', '', zoomScale, '');
   });
   ```

   Alter the script to contain the correct map instance ID (obtained in step 2 - in this example, it is `p_lt_ctl00_GoogleMapsWithUniqueID_map`), and the Google maps webpart control ID for the `latitude`, `longitude` and `zoomScale` variables (in this example, it is `GoogleMapsWithUniqueID`).

**This solution might cease to function correctly if you alter the layout, or move the webpart.** The ID of the map is hardcoded, and the solution would be to use jQuery to dynamically locate the map and obtain the ID.

The IDs are not stored in any global variables, hence the solution of hardcoding the ID.

Comment: After further questions to the OP, he's using the Static Google Maps, so no need to perform these actions, just provide a lat and long to place a pin on the map.